# How to get the name in facebook and silverlight?

Tags: facebook, silverlight-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to get the name and only the name.

Like this shows everything:

```
fb.GetAsync("me", (val) =>
            {
                if (val.Error == null)
                {
                    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)val.Result;
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => InfoBox.ItemsSource = result);
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO: Need to let the user know there was an error
                    //failedLogin();
                }
            });
```

So how do I just get the name?

regards
Even

Answer (score 0):

I'm JeongSeop Kim. Korean.

You can access infomation by using **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()** func.

for example.

**Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => firstNameTxtBlock.Text = result["first_name"].ToString());**

Maybe you can see:)

Good Lock!